# making sub list from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

I have a list

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 2}, {1, 4, 2,3},
{1, 4, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3, 4}, {2, 1, 4, 3}, {2, 3, 1, 4}, {2, 3,4, 1},
{2, 4, 1, 3}, {2, 4, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2, 4}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 2, 1, 4},
{3, 2, 4, 1}, {3, 4, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 2, 1}, {4, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 1, 3, 2},
{4, 2, 1, 3}, {4, 2, 3, 1}, {4, 3, 1, 2}, {4, 3, 2, 1}}
```

I want to make them this way- `{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 3}},...`

Which code should I use?

Comment: ArrayReshape, Partition etc.

Comment: `list // {#[[All, ;; 2]], #[[All, -2 ;;]]} & // Transpose ` and `TakeDrop[#, 2] & /@ list` are other possibilities.

Answer (score 6):

Besides [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html?q=Partition) and [`Map` (`/@`)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html?q=Map), you can also use [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html):

```
ArrayReshape[list, {Length@list, 2, 2}]
```

Answer (score 5):

One way is to partition each element in your list into a list of two elements:

```
Partition[#, 2] & /@ list
```

Where `list` is your example list.

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3}, {1, 3, 2, 4}};

list /. {a_, b_, c_, d_} :> {{a, b}, {c, d}}
```

or

```
{{#1, #2}, {#3, #4}} & @@@ list
```

both give

> {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 3}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}}